# How to get values of a listtext through Views?

Tags: views

on one of my content types I have a list (text) field with the following values.

> 100|Of essential importance
>  75|Of major importance
>  50|Of
>   medium importance
>  25|Of limited importance
>  00|Of no
>   importance
>  0|Don’t know

Now I created a View for this ContentType.  In the View, I want to display only the keys (e.g. 100, 75, 50) instead of the values (e.g. Of essential importance, Of major importance etc.)

Any help?